# Efficient and accurate approximatiion of logarithm of binomial coefficients

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, binomial-coefficients, approximation

I am searching for an efficient and accurate way to approximate the logarithm of binomial coefficients since I have to deal with extremely large numbers in C++. Using Stirling approximation, I am able to compute values very fast:

$ln\binom{n}{k} \approx n\cdot ln(n) - m\cdot ln(k) - (n-k)\cdot ln(n-k) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot (ln(n) - ln(k) - ln(n-k) - ln(2\pi))$

However, the approximation is not very accurate. Since I am not very strong in numerical analysis, I would like to know if there is a better way to approximate $ln\binom{n}{k}$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show a concrete example where the approximation is poor. If $\ n\ $ , $\ k\ $ and $\ n-k\ $ are all large, the approximation should be good. Additionally, where is $\ k\ $ in the approximation ?

Comment: In PARI/GP, you can use the lngamma-command for very accurate logarithms of huge binomial coefficients.

Comment: Crosspost from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55552775/approximating-the-lograrithm-of-binomial-coefficients-for-very-large-numbers, there also with the specification that $n\sim 10^7$.

Comment: @ LutzL: I have to apologize for the crosspost - I wasn't sure where to post this problem and since it is a computational as well as a numerical issue, I thought it might be appropriate for both sections. I should have chosen one, so indeed a beginner's mistake from my side.
@ Peter: Thank you very much for this! This might actually do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)! \, k!}=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n-k+1)\,\Gamma(k+1)}$$
$$\log (\binom{n}{k})=\log(\Gamma(n+1))-\log(\Gamma(n-k+1))-\log(\Gamma(k+1))$$

Now, have a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/lgamma/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't aware that the solution could be this simple. It works, is fast and accurate. Great!